# Bootstrap Navbar is taking up too much space on small screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a responsive website using bootstrap 3. There is a problem with the collapsed navbar where instead of it the normal height (i.e. height of one nav link item) it is taking up the total height of all the nav link items. Here is a screenshot of what I'm talking about http://tinyurl.com/pr4hae5

Here is my HTML, I have not overridden any of the default Bootstrap CSS.

```
<!-- Static navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Executive Committee</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Service Offerings</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Schedule</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Membership</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Contact Us<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
```

Comment: Do you mind providing an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/v3sevk6d/) with the other relevant CSS?

Comment: As a suggestion for your future posts, in jsfiddle.net you can write your code to share easily. It will be easier than using an image. In Stackoverflow, when you share a jsfiddle link, you must write the code as you did.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

<title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

  </div>
  <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Executive Committee</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Service Offerings</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Schedule</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Membership</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Contact Us<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div><!--/.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div class="container">

  <div class="starter-template">
    <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
    <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
  </div>
</div><!-- /.container -->


<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is working just fine...
Just added your navbar to the [starter template](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/)
And changed:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
```

into

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
```

I think you forgot the javascript in your code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

On getbootstrap.com

> Requires JavaScript plugin If JavaScript is disabled and the viewport
>   is narrow enough that the navbar collapses, it will be impossible to
>   expand the navbar and view the content within the .navbar-collapse.
>
> The responsive navbar requires the collapse plugin to be included in
>   your version of Bootstrap.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I had both those files included though they were on my machine not hosted online. I tried it anyway but didn't work. I suppose the issue may be in my css?

Comment: You can always use <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the issue. In my css, there was this bit:

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    text-align: center
    display: block !important;
    height: auto !important;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

I removed all rules but the text-align and the navbar is working as it should.

Thank you all for your assistance.